# EKS aws-ebs-csi-driver failed to mount volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

We are using EKS varsion v1.17.17-eks-087e67

With installed aws-ebs-csi-driver components versions:

- aws-ebs-csi-driver:v1.1.3
- csi-provisioner:v2.1.1
- csi-attacher:v3.1.0
- csi-snapshotter:v3.0.3
- csi-resizer:v1.0.0

When we create PVC driver could not mount volume. As I can see, AWS volume continuously creating and deleting (from cloud trail):

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAV5QH66QYOM4FMMPFI:1631165222580844502",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/EKSEBSCSIServiceRole-cluster01-eks-external-sandbox/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "accessKeyId": "ASIAV5QH66QYFCKRZG43",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAV5QH66QYOM4FMMPFI",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/eks/EKSEBSCSIServiceRole-cluster01-eks-external-sandbox",
                "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                "userName": "EKSEBSCSIServiceRole-cluster01-eks-external-sandbox"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {
                "federatedProvider": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "attributes": {}
            },
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2021-09-09T05:27:03Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2021-09-09T06:11:12Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateVolume",
    "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "18.157.68.62",
    "userAgent": "aws-sdk-go/1.35.37 (go1.15.6; linux; amd64) exec-env/aws-ebs-csi-driver-v1.1.3",
    "requestParameters": {
        "size": "8",
        "zone": "eu-central-1a",
        "volumeType": "gp2",
        "encrypted": true,
        "tagSpecificationSet": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "resourceType": "volume",
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "key": "ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster",
                            "value": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "CSIVolumeName",
                            "value": "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
                            "value": "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
                            "value": "data-postgres-postgresql-0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace",
                            "value": "default"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "requestId": "5404a63c-a8d6-4bfa-b18f-ce1fba1060ee",
        "volumeId": "vol-032b5c6671123cc35",
        "size": "8",
        "zone": "eu-central-1a",
        "status": "creating",
        "createTime": 1631167872000,
        "volumeType": "gp2",
        "iops": 100,
        "encrypted": true,
        "masterEncryptionKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:key/ef3b2237-00c3-4fd0-b556-91cda7f7db95",
        "tagSet": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "key": "CSIVolumeName",
                    "value": "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
                    "value": "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
                    "value": "data-postgres-postgresql-0"
                },
                {
                    "key": "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace",
                    "value": "default"
                }
            ]
        },
        "multiAttachEnabled": false
    },
    "requestID": "5404a63c-a8d6-4bfa-b18f-ce1fba1060ee",
    "eventID": "0941702c-119c-45fb-8c9e-6ef8918db6da",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eventCategory": "Management"
}
```

```
  "eventTime": "2021-09-09T06:11:15Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "DeleteVolume",
    "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "x.x.x.x",
    "userAgent": "aws-sdk-go/1.35.37 (go1.15.6; linux; amd64) exec-env/aws-ebs-csi-driver-v1.1.3",
    "errorCode": "Client.InvalidVolume.NotFound",
    "errorMessage": "The volume 'vol-032b5c6671123cc35' does not exist.",
    "requestParameters": {
        "volumeId": "vol-032b5c6671123cc35"
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "3cf2ce00-5845-436b-8470-3e1918dd24af",
    "eventID": "e5fbd13c-fc72-4cc1-9468-2a928d52a186",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eventCategory": "Management"
}
```

But eventually provisioner could not find this volume

```
0909 06:11:12.088851       1 controller.go:1332] provision "default/data-postgres-postgresql-0" class "ebs-default": started
I0909 06:11:12.089028       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"data-postgres-postgresql-0", UID:"27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"145344106", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Provisioning' External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/data-postgres-postgresql-0"
I0909 06:11:15.565942       1 controller.go:1099] Final error received, removing PVC 27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2 from claims in progress
W0909 06:11:15.565962       1 controller.go:958] Retrying syncing claim "27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2", failure 18
E0909 06:11:15.565981       1 controller.go:981] error syncing claim "27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2": failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ebs-default": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2": failed to get an available volume in EC2: InvalidVolume.NotFound: The volume 'vol-032b5c6671123cc35' does not exist.
        status code: 400, request id: a396c26c-71c6-4c88-8f2f-ebb3aa492447
I0909 06:11:15.566164       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"default", Name:"data-postgres-postgresql-0", UID:"27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"145344106", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' failed to provision volume with StorageClass "ebs-default": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-27fa1e04-c99d-48d2-9efa-0633ee3669d2": failed to get an available volume in EC2: InvalidVolume.NotFound: The volume 'vol-032b5c6671123cc35' does not exist.
        status code: 400, request id: a396c26c-71c6-4c88-8f2f-ebb3aa492447
```

Here is the policy from AWS Role for annotated CA:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:ModifyVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is StorageClass:

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: ebs-default
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  encrypted: "true"
  type: gp2
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
~
```

We are running workers in eu-central-1 region in 3 AZ

Comment: I'm getting the same error, can you pls let me know how you resolved it, we are using eks1.23 cluster

Comment: Here is what helped to me https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/enable-iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

The missing OpenID Connect provider in IAM service.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a document. Please do let me know if this helps.

Use this [GitHub Page Link](https://github.com/parjun8840/ekscsidriver/blob/main/README.md)!

Follow it from Step 2 - https://github.com/parjun8840/ekscsidriver/blob/main/README.md